# Xcode old version not showing 'Alamofire' and its methods in autocompletion

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding `Alamofire` to my `Xcode 8` project and everything works fine but when I start typing "Alamo.." there are no `Alamofire` related results in the `autocompletion`. Even if write `Alamofire`. (with the period at the end) there are still no autocompletion suggestions. I tried installing the framework via `CocoaPods` and manually and it didn't work both ways. I also tried adding the ($inherited) non recursive to the Header Search Paths of my project but still without success. I have imported `Alamofire` to my class!

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes it is a problem of Xcode to don't show autocompletion just quit Xcode and start again

Comment: Try building it first by cmd+B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the issue with 'Alamofire' pod.

Since you are using older version of Xcode you may need to install older version of Alamofire too.
insert this in your pod file

> For Swift 3:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '2.0'
```

> For Swift 4

```
pod 'Alamofire', '3.0'
```

Then run `pod install` again in the terminal.

Then what you need to do is

(1) Import the module by typing `import Alamofire` in your viewController class or any of your desired class.

(2) Build (press cmd+B) your project to link the Alamofire library.

(3) Then you have to type `Alamofire`(Case sensitive) manually. Then type `.` to see and select the related API methods in auto-completion.